# onClick and setImagResource [Android] API 10

Tags: android-layout

I'm trying to understand why it's occuring me the following problem.
I have an ImageView and i set an image to it, then i setup a onClickListener to it, so when you click to image it change the image (to a new image) by image01.setImageResource(R.drawable.newImage). After that i call a method where i check a condition, if it is true i change the image again to the default one.
But I can't see the change because it change immediately. I also insert a sleep to make it slower.
(By default in the xml code i setted the image to oldImage)

Ok... maybe it's not clear.. so let's see the CODE:

```
private void myMethod(){
        ImageView image01 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image01);
        image01.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
              @Override
              public void onClick(View v) {
              //When you click on image it change!
              image01.setImageResource(R.drawable.newImage);
              checkImg(image01);
              }
        });
}


private void checkGame(ImageView img){
        try{
           Thread.sleep(1000);  

           if(condition)
               img.setImageResource(R.drawable.oldImage);

        }catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

I saw immediately the oldImage. What's the problem? 
Is it possible that the view change are not applied in myMethod() until all methods inside it will terminate?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Using Thread.sleep() method, you are actually making wait to main UI thread. The main UI thread's methods are not synchronized. Be aware of that.

Please go through the developers.android site for using of threads painlessly... before seeing the your useful code.

```
private void myMethod(){
        ImageView image01 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image01);
        image01.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
              @Override
              public void onClick(View v) {
              //When you click on image it change!
              image01.setImageResource(R.drawable.newImage);
              checkGame(image01);
              }
        });
}


private void checkGame(ImageView img){
        try{
          // Thread.sleep(1000);  

           if(condition)
         image01.postDelayed(new Runnable() {                   
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                                 image01.setImageResource(R.drawable.oldImage);

}
                }, 2000);              

        }catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```